# Does gnome-terminal support DOS code pages?

Tags: c, command-prompt, codepages, gnome-terminal

In my C program I've had to swap my unicode box-drawing characters into escaped characters for DOS code page 437 to get it to work in the Windows command prompt. Is it possible to change the code page of gnome-terminal to display these characters correctly when natively compiling the program for linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://nethackwiki.com/wiki/IBMgraphics

> The current gnome-terminal does not
>   have a setting for code page 437, but
>   it does support other code pages that
>   are equivalent for NetHack's purposes,
>   such as 862 (Hebrew).
>
> To set code page 862 on
>   gnome-terminal:
>
> - Select Terminal->Set Character Encoding->Add or Remove.
> - In the pane on the left, select the line with description Hebrew and
>     encoding IBM862.
> - Click the right-pointing arrow between the two panes.
> - Click Close.
>
> The above steps only need to be done
>   once for the lifetime of the Gnome
>   installation. Once done, it is
>   sufficient to:
>
> - Select Terminal, Set Character Encoding, and then Hebrew (IBM862).
>
> It should be noted that the current
>   default gnome-terminal font in Ubuntu
>   Jaunty fully supports DECgraphics as
>   long as eight_bit_tty is set to false.

Comment: +1 for an answer from Nethack! Then +1 to the other answer because it's more robust and makes more sense. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need these characters, you should use their correct Unicode codepoint values and output them as UTF-8. Or, if you prefer, you can output them as wide characters and let the standard library's locale system take care of converting them to UTF-8 or another "native" encoding the user has selected (which might even be CP437, although I've never seen a system setup that poorly...).

Comment: That's what i did originally, but Window's command prompt is so poor that it doesn't support Unicode well enough by default without workarounds, so I converted them to code page 437 characters. The conversion of wide characters I don't really understand, but typically they end up going to + and | rather than the proper box drawing characters.

Comment: Rather than breaking your program and requiring ugly workarounds on correct systems, I would simply make some sort of wrapper layer on windows to convert the Unicode to DOS codepage characters..

Comment: It's not a [command prompt](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/command-prompts.html), [it's a console](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/a-command-interpreter-is-not-a-console.html), and the [WriteConsoleW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API function is quite capable of writing Unicode to a console.  All of this mucking about with code pages is rather missing the point that underneath consoles use Unicode on Windows NT.